# JQuery, wrong left position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code:

```
$(this).closest("p").after('<strong>' + arMess[iCurIndex] + '</strong>').next().animate({
            top: $(this).offset().top - 57,
            left: -$(this).width() //[First value] Here i get 148px on chrome and 150px on firefox

        }, 300,function(){
            alert($(this).offset().top - 57);
            alert(-$(this).width()); //[Second value] Here i get the true width the one i want to present the left
        });
```

Code overview:
**At the first line** i animate the **STRONG** element

As you can see i get 2 different values from **-$(this).width()**:

**The first value:** I get during the animation process.

**The second value:** I get after the animation finished.

If anyone got idea about the reason i get 2 different values, I will be very thankful.

Comment: I can just guess.. Probably problem with borders? Try to use `outerWidth` instead of `width`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the javascript keyword *this* does not have the same value in the inner function that is called after the animation as it does when you are setting the width. For the first value *this* is the object that triggers the animation. In the function where the alert is called *this* is the object that is being animated.

Try this:

```
var $strongElement = $(this).closest("p").after('<strong>' + arMess[iCurIndex] + '</strong>').next();

$strongElement.animate({
       top: $(this).offset().top - 57,
       left: -$strongElement.width() 
    }, 300, function(){
    alert(-$(this).width()); 
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/vtyjf/

Comment: Thank you so much moiter, I was trying to find a solution over 6 hours i think,  If you can tell me why are you using the dollar($) before a variable?

Comment: To show it is a jQuery object. It's just a quite helpful naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

Try [outerWidth](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) or check your element's css if it got `float:left`

```
$(this).closest("p").after('<strong>' + arMess[iCurIndex] + '</strong>').next().animate({
            top: $(this).offset().top - 57,
            left: -$(this).outerWidth();
                         // use .outerWidth(true); if you want to 
                         //calculate with margin and border values

}, 300,function(){
            alert($(this).offset().top - 57);
            alert(-$(this).outerWidth());
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Barlas, But this is have nothing to do with the padding of margin, The problem is that i get different values, I think it is something with browser default value(Chrome=148px, Firefox=150px), As the question above.

Comment: No i am not, Should i use it before every css?

Comment: @uBlankText it would be a good idea to use it. It standardizes the browsers default values. Try to put some css reset and then try with  Barlas answer.

Comment: I did try but same result, Any other solution?